# How to set two dynamic temporary global variables for triggers in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers, global-variables

I have a stored procedure to update data, which is being called through C#. I also have several triggers set to my table which insert audit information to audit table when the data is changed.

The problem is I have two columns in audit table called changedBy(UserName) and changeSetID, which I can only retrieve them from C#, I can pass them as parameters to the stored procedure, then I don't know how to let trigger get the value of these two variables.

Originally I use context_info as a global variable, but I need to pass two variables to trigger.

Comment: The only way I saw as a way to get multiples...was to have a "LastChangedBy" and "LastChangeSetId" columns... on the original table...so you can get at that info.....in the trigger on the @inserted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured out a workaround about this.

First, I pass my username and changesetID from C# to SQL stored procedure as parameters. Inside my stored procedure, I set CONTEXT_INFO to the combination of userName and changeSetID

```
Declare @userAndSetID VARBINARY(128)
SET @UserName = @UserName + ',' + @ChangeSetID + ','
SET @userAndSetID = CAST(CAST(@UserName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS VARBINARY(128));
SET CONTEXT_INFO @userAndSetID
```

And Inside my trigger, I retrieve my two variables from CONTEXT_INFO(), by using split string function:

```
 select @ChangedBy = value from dbo.fn_Split((CAST (CONTEXT_INFO() AS NVARCHAR(MAX))),',') where position = 1;
 select @changesetID = value from dbo.fn_Split((CAST (CONTEXT_INFO() AS NVARCHAR(MAX))),',') where position = 2;
```

And here is the split string function, it gets a string separated by whatever symbol, and put them to a table variable row by row:

```
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Split](@text nvarchar(MAX), @delimiter nvarchar(20) = ' ')
    RETURNS @Strings TABLE
    (    
      position int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
      value nvarchar(1500)   
    )
    AS
    BEGIN

    DECLARE @index int
    SET @index = -1 

    WHILE (LEN(@text) > 0) 

      BEGIN 
        SET @index = CHARINDEX(@delimiter , @text)  
        IF (@index = 0) AND (LEN(@text) > 0)  
          BEGIN  
            INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (@text)
              BREAK  
          END 

        IF (@index > 1)  
          BEGIN  
            INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (LEFT(@text, @index - 1))   
            SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index))  
          END 
        ELSE
          SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index)) 
        END
      RETURN

    END
```

This is just a workaround, as @Tab Alleman suggested, the best way to solve this problem is to save the variables somewhere inside database, but since I don't want to modify the database at the moment, this solution will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Several approaches:

1)   As granadaCoder, suggested, add those columns to your updated table, so that the trigger will be able to access them

2)  Disable the trigger at the beginning of your proc, include the inserts to the audit tables in your proc (instead of letting the trigger do them), then re-enable the trigger at the end.

3)  Keep this information in a permanent table.   Have a table with the UniqueID of your updated table, and the "changedBy" and "changeSetID" columns.   At the beginning of the proc, update this table with the parameters passed from C#.  In the trigger, join inserted to this table to get the values of the two columns you need.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a better way to do this, if SQL 2016 is being used Through [SESSION_CONTEXT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/session-context-transact-sql)

Insert 
EXEC sys.sp_set_session_context @key = N'ID', @value = 'Some Text', @read_only = 1;

Read Out
    PRINT SESSION_CONTEXT(N'ID');

And for the second option you could specify a different Key